# Best way to use Python Enum or Dictionary for mapping constants and staying DRY with inference

Tags: python, enums, constants, dry, inference

I just started using Python for server-side programming (coming from TypeScript) and the verbosity of typing `.value` for an Enum is making me consider not using it at all.

In TypeScript the value of an Enum is retrieved like so..

```js
enum CompassDirection {
  North = "North",
}

// I do not have to ask for the value
const isEqual = CompassDirection.North === "North" ? true : false

console.log(isEqual) // returns true
```

But in Python I believe the only way to retrieve the value is using `.value` like so..

```py
from enum import Enum

class CompassDirection(Enum):
    NORTH = 'NORTH'

isEqual = CompassDirection.NORTH == 'NORTH'
print(isEqual) // false

isEqual = CompassDirection.NORTH.value == 'NORTH'
print(isEqual) // true
```

My purpose of using Enum was for inference and so I wouldn't have to repeatedly type strings such as "NORTH" all in my code.

If I made a function I would have to call it everywhere as well - **e.g.**

```py
def get_enum_value(enum): 
   return enum.value

# Calling this every time I want to use the enum.
get_enum_value(CompassDirection.NORTH)
get_enum_value(XEnum.Value)
get_enum_value(YEnum.Value)
```

Yet if I do not do this, this I'm repeatedly typing `.value` everywhere, which I'm finding counter-intuitive maybe because of my TypeScript bias.

Is there a way I can use Enum or a Dictionary achieve the inference that I want, keep my code as DRY as possible so I can avoiding typing my strings?

**Note:**

I don't mind making a few constants but I could see my imports getting lengthy for code-splitting / re-use.

Am I missing something? I'd like to understand this as soon as possible.

Comment: If you simply don't inherit `Enum` at all, the class with string attributes will behave like you wanted. So is there really some feature from `Enum` that you _do_ need?

Comment: I don't know why your question would get downvoted as long as it's a valid question that follows SO guidelines - which it seems to do.

Comment: The main value of `Enum` is that the *compiler* can catch a typo like `Nroth`. A string like `"Nroth"` will go undetected until your program misbehaves.  `isEqual = CompassDirection.North == CompassDirection(x)`. You'll get an immediate error if `x` is not a valid direction.

Comment: One other option is to do a direct equality check in function. This is much more convenient. For example, `x = CompassDirection.NORTH; assert x is CompassDirection.NORTH # true`. Of course, this is assuming you don't really need to retrieve the value of the enum

Comment: For checking if Enum is *not* a specified member or name, you can similarly use an `is not` check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate solution to your problem is to inherit from `str` as well as from `Enum`<sup>1</sup>:

```
class CompassDirection(str, Enum):
    NORTH = 'NORTH'

>>> print(CompassDirection.NORTH == 'NORTH')
True
```

The long-term solution is to realize that you should no longer be using strings, but the enum members, and using `is`:

```
somevar = CompassDirections.NORTH
#
# some intervening code
#
print(somevar is CompassDirections.NORTH)
# True
```

You should only have to deal with the string `"NORTH"` if getting input from a user, a configuration file, etc., and then you'll want to immediately convert to an Enum:

```
result = input('Enter direction')
result = CompassDirection(result.upper())
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Python 3.11 will have a `StrEnum` type, which will ensure that the values are already of type `str`.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This is great! I'm also excited for `StrEnum` which sounds like a pretty cool idea.